# Perspective transformation without manual points

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to computer vision and image processing. I have an image which is distorted(3D). On going through the articles I came to know about perspective transformations on image but all codes involve manual points being used as an input along with the image. Now I will be having a lot of images with different types of distortions so manually entering edge points isn't an option. Can anyone suggest what can be done? I basically need to do character detection from images and hence I first need to rectify the image. [Adding the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mFeO.jpg)

I tried direct character detection using this code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import imutils

img = cv2.imread("hel2.png")


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
# plt.show()

# turn into gray for next processing
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)


# find the contour
cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]

result = img.copy()
for c in cntrs:
    # for each letter, create red rectangle
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,0,0), 2)



%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imgplot = plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()
```

But this code is not able to create bounding boxes for characters in the borders of the distorted image.